Qt: Passing pointer to member slot function
I'm trying to pass a Qt slot member function to a static function and get a compiler error. I think because the argument type slotfunction is wrong.
Here's a very short code example of my problem:
typedef void (MainWindow::*slotfunction)();

QAction* AddAction(QMenu* menu
                   , QString name
                   , QObject* receiver
                   ,  slotfunction slotFkt
                   ) {
    QAction* action = new QAction(name, receiver);
    QObject::connect(action, &QAction::triggered, receiver, slotFkt);
    menu->addAction(action);
    return action;
}


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent) {
    QMenu* fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("File"));
    AddAction(fileMenu, tr("New"), this, &MainWindow::onFileNew);
}

The error is:
mainwindow.cpp(24): error C2665: 'QObject::connect': none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qobject.h(481): note: could be 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const'
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qobject.h(225): note: or       'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const QMetaMethod &,const QObject *,const QMetaMethod &,Qt::ConnectionType)'
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qobject.h(222): note: or       'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)'
C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qobject.h(242): note: or       'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect<void(__cdecl QAction::* )(bool),slotfunction>(const QAction *,Func1,const MainWindow *,Func2,Qt::ConnectionType)'
        with
        [
            Func1=void (__cdecl QAction::* )(bool),
            Func2=slotfunction
        ]
mainwindow.cpp(24): note: while trying to match the argument list '(QAction *, void (__cdecl QAction::* )(bool), QObject *, slotfunction)'


The short answer is that AddAction accepts a QObject * as the receiver type but QObject has no member named onFileNew.  The fix depends on a few things: is the receiver arg always going to be of type MainWindow * or can it be a pointer to anything that inherits from QObject?  Perhaps the easy solution would be to make the slotFtk arg an std::function<void()> and just pass a lambda.

That worked perfectly. Thank you.

Using G.M.'s suggestion, here's the solution:
QAction* AddAction(QMenu* menu
                   , QString name
                   , QString tooltip
                   , QObject* receiver
                   ,  std::function<void()> slotFkt
                  ) {

    QAction* action = new QAction(name, receiver);
    action->setToolTip(tooltip);
    QObject::connect(action, &QAction::triggered, receiver, slotFkt);
    menu->addAction(action);
    return action;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) {
    QMenu* menu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("File"));
    AddAction(menu, tr("New"), tr("Create a new file"), this, [&]() {onFileNew();});
}

slots
void MainWindow::onFileNew() {
}


The reason why Qt compiler generates that error is because the signatures of 2 functions don't match each other.
    with
    [
        Func1=void (__cdecl QAction::* )(bool),
        Func2=slotfunction
    ]

with the slotFunction has the prototype of void(MainWindow::*)()
With Qt signal slots mechanism, it requires signal - signal, signal-slot, signal-function have the same signatures
With the GM's solution solved the issue because the std::function allows us to receive the number of arguments and invoke the function inside with different arguments
